# Unable to Compile Particle-Qt using qmake in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: compiling, quarkcoin

Good Day!

I am trying to compile the Particle-Qt Client on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid Velvet using GCC 5.0 & libboost1.55

So my system is throwing errors, these are the following:

While executing `qmake`, I am getting this:

```
Project MESSAGE: Building with UPNP support
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Removed plural forms as the target language has less forms.
If this sounds wrong, possibly the target language is not set or recognized.
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Removed plural forms as the target language has less forms.
If this sounds wrong, possibly the target language is not set or recognized.
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
Warning: ignoring <defaultcodec> element
```

And When Executing Make I am getting:

```
cd /media/red_gene/DeOxyRibose/Particle_REACQ/src/leveldb && CC=gcc CXX=g++ make OPT="-m64 -pipe -fstack-protector-all -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2" libleveldb.a libmemenv.a
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/red_gene/DeOxyRibose/Particle_REACQ/src/leveldb'
make[1]: 'libleveldb.a' is up to date.
make[1]: 'libmemenv.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/red_gene/DeOxyRibose/Particle_REACQ/src/leveldb'
cd /media/red_gene/DeOxyRibose/Particle_REACQ; /bin/sh share/genbuild.sh /media/red_gene/DeOxyRibose/Particle_REACQ/build/build.h
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /media/red_gene/DeOxyRibose)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -fstack-protector-all -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -D_REENTRANT -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstack-protector -fPIE -DQT_GUI -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -DUSE_IPV6=1 -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -DLINUX -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -Isrc -Isrc/json -Isrc/qt -Isrc/leveldb/include -Isrc/leveldb/helpers -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -Ibuild -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -o build/bitcoin.o src/qt/bitcoin.cpp
src/qt/bitcoin.cpp:5:24: fatal error: QApplication: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:1106: recipe for target 'build/bitcoin.o' failed
make: *** [build/bitcoin.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here:

```
QApplication: No such file or directory
```

You might not have QT development files installed.

If using debian / ubuntu try:

```
apt-get install libqt4-dev
```

Comment: Had to remove qt5-qmake and replace with qt4-qmake!

Comment: Had to remove qt5-qmake and replace with qt4-qmake! -> how to do this?